Getting list of files and folders from the public link
I want to get a list of files and folders from a Nextcloud public link on Vue project.
I can get a list with file path.
const client = webdav.createClient(webdavURL, {
username: username,
password: password,
});
const directoryItems = await client.getDirectoryContents("/Documents/test");
But, I want directoryItems with shared public url instead of path
